# jquery accordion tab index using header element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

//    html

```
<div id="accordion" >
   <h3 class='headAcc' id="head_1">First header</h3>
   <div>First content panel</div>
   <h3 class='headAcc'id="head_2">Second header</h3>
   <div>Second content panel</div>
</div>
```

//javascript

```
$('#accordion').accordion({collapsible:true,active:false});
```

Question:  all the tabs are closed on default. So I need to get the index of a tab using header element id. How can I do that.

I have tried following. But no luck. Thanks in advance.

```
var indexOfheaderOne= $('h3#head_1').index(); //returns 0 which is ok
var indexOfheaderTwo= $('h3#head_2').index(); // returns 2 instead of 1. 

//I think the reason is it will count the indexes based on all sibling elements
//not just from header elements. Is there any workaround for this.
```

## **EDIT**

Little modification for @Thusar Solution

Suppose that your html contains more `<h3>` elements outside accordion. Then following work around will work for that type of scenario.

HTML

```
<h3 id="test1">Example Head 1</h3> 
<h3 id="test2">Example Head 2</h3> 
<h3 id="test3">Example Head 3</h3> 

<div id="accordion" >
   <h3 class='headAcc' id="head_1">First header</h3>
   <div>First content panel</div>
   <h3 class='headAcc'id="head_2">Second header</h3>
   <div>Second content panel</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
alert($('h3#head_1').index('h3.headAcc'));//return 0 as expected
alert($('h3#head_2').index());//return 2 because element is in after first tab div
alert($('h3#head_2').index('h3.headAcc'));//return 1 as expected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/SvssC/)

```
var indexOfheaderTwo= $('h3#head_2').index('h3'); //returns 1 as index of h3 with respect to parent is traced and it is the 2nd child of parent with tag h3.
```

Index starts from 0.

Explanation of the problem.

```
var indexOfheaderOne= $('h3#head_1').index(); //returns 0 As it is first child of parent div

var indexOfheaderTwo= $('h3#head_2').index(); // returns 2 As it is third child of parent div
```

Read [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index)

Comment: awesome bro. That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption on why it is returning 2 is right.

Change your index selector to as follows:

```
var indexOfheaderOne= $('h3').index($('#head_1')); //returns 0 which is ok
var indexOfheaderTwo= $('h3').index($('#head_2')); // returns 1.
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GxQ3c/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", i);
```

have you try this one ? with accordion it might be in-built function.

Try Demo [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SvssC/3/).